# How to disable an activity containing a special character?

Tags: adb, disable-app

What is the correct way to disable the activity:

```
com.android.settings/.Settings$SystemDashboardActivity
```

When I try to disable it via `pm disable` command it disables the whole Settings activity and not the specific activity *SystemDashboardActivity*.

Note: I have a rooted device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the dollar character. Otherwise, the shell would interpret  anything after $ as the variable name. Since `$SystemDashboardActivity` as a variable is not set, your command is effectively interpreted as:

```
pm disable com.android.settings/.Settings
```

That naturally would disable the parent (`.Settings`) component.

Escape $ by prefixing it with `\` so as to prevent unwanted interpretation from shell.  Your command should look like this:

```
pm disable com.android.settings/.Settings\$SystemDashboardActivity
```

Tested on Android 9.0 running on OnePlus 6. Make sure to run the command as root.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105409/discussion-on-answer-by-firelord-how-to-disable-an-activity-containing-a-special).